# upload to attribute in django with FileField

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

I face a problem with FileField I can't upload any files in admin page, every time I tried to upload I got this message
Bad Request (400)

while the code is as below:

IDAttached = models.FileField(upload_to='/documents/%Y/%m/',null=True, blank= True)

Thank you for support,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without the first slash:

```
IDAttached = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/',null=True, blank= True)
```

If it still doesn't work, make sure you have MEDIA_ROOT in setting.py properly configured.